# iPhone - Transparent status bar does not resize subviews

Tags: iphone

I have two viewcontrollers in my app, one of them shows an opaque status bar (default) while the other shows a black translucent status bar.

When I come from the first view controller to the other, in viewWillDisappear of controller1, I specify this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

The autoresizing mask of controller2 is set as follows

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

But even then, when controller2's view appears, the view begins from right below the status bar. I see a white space below the status bar. When the status bar is hidden after 3 seconds, the view adjusts and covers the white space. When the view is again tapped to show the status bar, the view shifts down to leave white space below the status bar.

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

**More Info**

This is only a problem with 3.x. With 2.2.1 the same code works fine and the view starts from behind the status bar.

Adding images to show what I mean
[alt text http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4008/withstatus.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4008/withstatus.png)

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6281/withoutstatus.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6281/withoutstatus.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to autoresize the view ? Can you not just set its frame to full screen ? That would force it under the bar.

Comment: I have that in place too. Tried frame and bounds but both give the same result.